# Moving controls inside a zoomed frame on an Excel Userform

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have Userform1 which is sized to fit full screen in a monitor of 2560 x 1440.  Userform1 contains FrameA whose .Width is also 2560, and which is zoomed to 10%.

FrameA contains a child FrameB, whose .Width is 8000 and whose .Left is 1000 (in FrameA zoomed coordinates).  FrameB is fully visible on screen.

I want to move FrameB to the right so that its right edge lies along the right edge of the monitor.  Could somebody show me the arithmetic for doing that?

Comment: Doe this help?  `A.Left + A.Width` gives the right boundary of A. `A.Left = B.Right - A.Width` will right align A with B.

Comment: So, using the numbers from my question, how far to the right would I move FrameB ?

Comment: Sorry I am day-dreaming here.  `A.Left = B.Right - A.Width ` is a nonesense because there is no B.Right.  I should have written `A.Left = (B.Left + B.Width) - A.Width`.  Also I think I got my As and Bs the opposite of yours.  Unless I misunderstand the significance of your question, you should not set FrameB's `.Left` to an absolute value based on the current screen because later you will use it on a different screen.

Comment: I handle the later use of a different screen by getting the actual screen dimensions (using getSystemMetrics) and making adjustments.

But I think you're missing the significance of the zoom.  So I repeat my question, using the numbers given, how far to the right should I move FrameB to abut its right edge to the right edge of the screen?

Comment: If the formula I gave you does not work, I do not know what to suggest.  That is how I align shapes.  I sometimes find the right border of the outer shape is further to the left than the value given suggests.  This either happens or it doesn't.  If it does, I have to had between 20 and 50 pixels to stop the inner shape losing its right edge.

Comment: Tony - I'd like to provide a sample so you can see what's happening. Here's a zipped wkb that demos the problem. [http://bit.ly/yxSNm0 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to do it.

Just to recap the problem and simplify it a bit:
Frame2 is fully contained inside a zoomed Frame1, and needs to be moved to the right so its right side is flush with the right side of Frame1. Where should the left side of the Frame2 be moved to?

```
Sub move_Frame2_Hard_Right_Inside_Frame1()
   Dim zoomPct!
   zoomPct! = Frame1.Zoom / 100
   Frame2.Left = Frame1.Width / zoomPct! - Frame2.Width
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not recall every having so much trouble getting a form to look the way I wanted.

I ended up moving lots of things around that did not, perhaps, need moving.  However, I have finally got the effect I believe you seek so I have not tried to move code back to where it was.

The first key change appears to be:

```
Property StartUpPosition of UserForm1 = 0 - Manual`
```

without this, I could not set the form's height to the full available height.  Setting .Top had no effect.

The second key change appears to be use of:

```
  Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
```

I do not recall needing this command before but maximizing the window state would not give the full screen height.

I discarded your routines `Sub maximizeWindows()` and `Sub UserForm_initialize()` either because I did things differently or because I moved the code.  I am sure you could move the code back but I have not tried.

I added a new control `cmdExit` with the following event routine:

```
Private Sub cmdExit_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub
```

`Sub runDemo()` has become:

```
Sub runDemo()

  Application.DisplayFullScreen = True

  Load UserForm1
  With UserForm1
    .Top = 2
    .Left = 0
    .Width = Application.UsableWidth
    .Height = Application.UsableHeight - 2
    .Frame1.Move 0, 0, .InsideWidth, 300
    .Frame2.Left = .Frame1.Left + .Frame1.InsideWidth - .Frame2.InsideWidth
    .Show
  End With

  Application.DisplayFullScreen = False

End Sub
```

The effect of the above for me was:

- UserForm1 occupied the entire screen apart from the Windows Task bar along the bottom.
- Frame1 was at the top, occupied the full width of the screen and had a height of 300.
- Frame2 was right aligned with Frame1.
- The maximized/normal/minimized state of Excel was not changed.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Tony, I appreciate your efforts, but as mentioned in my comment above, you're still totally ignoring the zoomed condition of the parent Frame. It's the zoomed parent frame that's at the heart of this question, as indicated in the title of the question, but there's no reference to zoom in your answer and you actually removed the zoom property for the parent frame from my sample Wkb. Try your code after setting the zoom of Frame1 back to 10%.

Comment: The Zoom simply reduces the size of Frame2.  It has no obvious effect on Frame1.  What do you want the screen to look like at the end of this initialisation?